# JS jquery rangeError - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anybody tell me what the following JS error means?

[image]
Everything working well.

I think it's probably because of this JS code snippet:

```
                <!--move cursor to the end of input value-->
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        jQuery.fn.putCursorAtEnd = function () {
                            return this.each(function () {
                                // Cache references
                                var $el = $(this),
                                    el = this;
                                // Only focus if input isn't already
                                if (!$el.is(":focus")) {
                                    $el.focus();
                                }
                                // If this function exists... (IE 9+)
                                if (el.setSelectionRange) {
                                    // Double the length because Opera is inconsistent about whether a carriage return is one character or two.
                                    var len = $el.val().length * 2;
                                    // Timeout seems to be required for Blink
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        el.setSelectionRange(len, len);
                                    }, 1);
                                } else {
                                    // As a fallback, replace the contents with itself
                                    // Doesn't work in Chrome, but Chrome supports setSelectionRange
                                    $el.val($el.val());
                                }
                                // Scroll to the bottom, in case we're in a tall textarea
                                // (Necessary for Firefox and Chrome)
                                this.scrollTop = 999999;
                            });

                        };

                        (function () {
                            var searchInput = $(".js-typeahead");
                            searchInput
                                .putCursorAtEnd() // should be chainable
                                .on("focus", function () { // could be on any event
                                    searchInput.putCursorAtEnd()
                                });
                        })();
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: The error means that you've created an infinite loop. My guess would be because you're running the function on `focus`, yet the function itself triggers a `focus` event, which runs itself again and so on. If you set a `debugger` in your code and step through it it should be easy to see where the recursive call is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because of

```
(function () {
    var searchInput = $(".js-typeahead");
    searchInput.putCursorAtEnd().on("focus", function () { 
        searchInput.putCursorAtEnd() //you are invoking putCursorAtEnd here
    });
})();
```

And in `putCursorAtEnd` you are setting the `focus` on the element back again

```
if (!$el.is(":focus")) {
      $el.focus();
}
```

Which is causing the **un-ending recursion since at the focus you are trying to put focus on it back again**.

Judging by what you doing are attempting, **instead of bind the event on focus again, do at `click`**

```
(function () {
    var searchInput = $(".js-typeahead");
    searchInput.putCursorAtEnd().on("click", function () {  //focus is changed to click
        searchInput.putCursorAtEnd();
    });
})();
```

Comment: Oh, now I see it! Work like a charm. Big THX for quick response.